# How to set Account for SQL Server service in configuration file?

Tags: sql-server

I want to install SQL Server 2017 by configuration file and I cannot find as can I set into Account for SQL Server service `{SQLSVCACCOUNT = ?}` value that will select log on as Local System account.

Is there a way to do that through configuration file ?

Answer (score 1):

I have saved one Sample of how you can specify the Local System account in the configuration file:

```
[OPTIONS]

; Specifies a Setup work flow, like INSTALL, UNINSTALL, or UPGRADE. This is a required parameter.
ACTION="Install"

; Specifies features to install, uninstall, or upgrade. The list of top-level features include SQL, AS, RS, IS, and Tools. The SQL feature will install the Database Engine, Replication, Full-Text, and Data Quality Services (DQS) server. The Tools feature will install Management Tools, Books online components, SQL Server Data Tools, and other shared components.
FEATURES=SQLENGINE

; Displays the command line parameters usage
HELP="False"

; Specifies that the detailed Setup log should be piped to the console.
INDICATEPROGRESS="False"

; Specifies that Setup should install into WOW64. This command line argument is not supported on an IA64 or a 32-bit system.
X86="False"

; Specifies the installation directory.
INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify the root installation directory for shared components.
INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify the instance root directory.
INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify the installation directory.
INSTALLSQLDATADIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Agent account name
SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"

; Auto-start service after installation.
AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Manual"

; Startup type for Integration Services.
ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; CM brick TCP communication port
COMMFABRICPORT="0"

; Set to "1" to enable feature.
FEATURES=SQLENGINE

; Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the TCP/IP protocol.
TCPENABLED="1"

; Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the Named Pipes protocol.
NPENABLED="0"

; Startup type for Browser Service.
BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled"
```

you can use the `SQLSVCACCOUNT` parameter to specify the account under which the SQL Server service will run.

Comment: Does this value SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" mean than sql server will log on as local system account ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Setting SQLSVCACCOUNT to "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" means that the SQL Server service will run under the Local System account.

Comment: `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` is a really bad idea, it should be a separate service user with lower permissions. Also why disable SQL Browser?

Comment: @Charlieface Agreed about the service account. That might make a good "Frame Challenge" answer. As for disabling the SQL Browser service, some security postures recommend it. And isn't it disabled by the default installation anyway if you only have a default instance?